# How to fix problem with text not showing in Preview mode for SSRS 2019 using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I just got the latest versions today for working with SSRS: SSRS 2019, Visual Studio Community 2019 (Version 4.8.03752) with SSRS Templates (Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers Version 15.0.1659.0).

I have a textbox with the report title which doesn't show in preview (both in header or body) and a textbox in footer with page counts that doesn't show. In the body I have a Table with a few columns that don't show values but do show the table cells. I noticed that values did show for returned records on first try but not for column headers; however, when I resized one cell, no values were shown at all for anything.  Now, no text values show at all in Preview mode.

When I export report to PDF, everything shows (title, body, footer). This also works when I published to the Portal.

Here is what I tried without success:

1. Changed the font color to all texts to red but text values still don't show.
2. Deleted the report data files (.data) but text values still don't show.
3. Open the report file (.rdl) with Report Builder but text values still don't show.

So, it is in the editors (VS and Report Builder) that the problem only exists as rendering (PDF, Word) works and running in Report Portal works.

Thanks.

Comment: delete those text items. save the report. Close project.. open project and place the text items back again.. should be ok. I have no idea why it does that.. I have had a nightmare of a time with the same issue! Interestingly, it prints fine.. just doesn't show up to view!

Comment: Thank you Harry.  I tried your instruction and it worked!   Before reading your comment, I installed everything on a different computer and it gave me the same problem of the textbox value not showing.  I simply added one textbox with value of "Test" and it did not display.  On my first computer, before reading your comment, I tried installing the Reporting Services add-in again but it did not work.  I then tried your steps but it did not work.  I did get strange error messages that seems the installation is corrupted.  So, I'm reinstalling everything again on that computer.

Comment: so.. did my comment help resolve the issue?

Comment: Yes and no.  I did get it to work sometimes but not always.  I basically added a textbox with "Test" as value.   Trying preview fails to show and then I followed your steps.  Sometimes it worked and sometimes it did not.  I then compared the source code of the page when it failed and when it worked.  I did not see any difference that will tell me why one version works and another version fails.  At this point, it is unusable as how can you develop without preview not being reliable.   Given you and I have experienced the same issue, it is likely others have too.  Solution isn't reliable I say.

Comment: I found a workaround that works for me but it is a pain.  The fix is to change the TextBox's CanGrow field to FALSE (defaults to TRUE).  However, the fix is impractical as it would take to much time to do this on every textbox (imagine doing this on a Table).  I also tried installing SSDT 2017 and to my surprise I had the same issue of Text values not showing in Preview. Got solution from: [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0241dff7-71a8-47b4-a03a-e1411bee3217/text-box-in-ssrs-not-showing-data-unless-i-untick-the-allow-height-to-increase?forum=dslvsarchx)

Answer (score 1):

My issue was resolved by unticking the "Allow height to increase" check box for the text box.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4cJm.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue using the standalone Report Builder application, and I resolved it by placing the textbox inside a rectangle. From then on, it rendered in preview mode as expected. However, I'm not sure how that would affect auto-growth.